# Backbone Trigger and On

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've used this function many times without fail but today I've hit a brick wall...

I've simplified the code but still the console does not fire. I can see the event in console of this.app

Any ideas or suggestions would be appicated.

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.trigger('selected');
        this.on('selected', this.render);
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('rendering??');
    },

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the event handler before you fire the event. So call `this.on` before you call `this.trigger`

```
return Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.on('selected', this.render);
        this.trigger('selected');
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('rendering??');
    },

});
```